# USB flash drive under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive

My system (2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu) does not bind plugged usb flash drives.

I can see devices with `lsusb` and I see `udevd` getting events from kernel:

```
KERNEL[1317495074.878775] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.3/usb1/1-3 (usb)
KERNEL[1317495074.880374] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1317495074.885273] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.3/usb1/1-3 (usb)
UDEV  [1317495074.889612] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0 (usb)
```

but no one device will be created.

What do I miss?

Comment: `modprobe usbstorage` somehow comes to mind... Run it as root, see if it helps.

Comment: @grawity: Yes, it was the solution. However the module wasnt loaded on startup.